# Codility StoneWell Problem Python - Code Fails on Performance Tests Due to Incorrect Responses

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, minimum

I'm trying to solve the [StoneWall](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/7-stacks_and_queues/stone_wall/) codility problem.

I came up with the following code:

```
def solution(H):
    if len(H) == 0: return 0
    if len(H) == 1: return 1
    count = 1
    potentialBases = {}
    for i in range(1, len(H)): 
        # print(potentialBases, count, H[i])
        if H[i] > H[i - 1]:
            count += 1 
            potentialBases[H[i-1]] = 1
        elif H[i] < H[i-1]:
            if H[i] not in potentialBases: 
                count += 1
                potentialBases[H[i]] = 1
            if H[i-1] in potentialBases: 
                potentialBases.pop(H[i-1])
    return count
```

This passes all the correctness tests (100%), but fails on pretty much all the performance tests - not because of time complexity issues, but because the values obtained are incorrect.

I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong here, but I can't seem to come up with a small example which makes the code fail.

Comment: you ned to make a stack to store the current height at index 0 and then from index 1 compare element from 1 to last of stack element, if last current element is > than stack last element then add current element in stack else pop the stack till current element is greater than stack element

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it with the following code:

```
def solution(H):
    if len(H) == 0: return 0
    if len(H) == 1: return 1
    count = 1
    potentialBases = {}
    for i in range(1, len(H)): 
        if H[i] > H[i - 1]:
            count += 1 
            potentialBases[H[i-1]] = 1
        elif H[i] < H[i-1]:
            if H[i] not in potentialBases: 
                count += 1
                potentialBases[H[i]] = 1
            if len(potentialBases.keys()) < H[i-1] + 1 - H[i]:
                keysToPop = []
                for key in potentialBases.keys(): 
                    if key >= H[i] and key <= H[i-1]: 
                        keysToPop.append(key)
                for key in keysToPop: 
                    potentialBases.pop(key)
            else: 
                for j in range(H[i], H[i-1] + 1):
                    if j in potentialBases:
                        potentialBases.pop(j)
    return count
```

The issue was occurring when the current value block height was smaller than the previous one. In my previous solution, I was just removing the previous block from my `potentialBases` dict (`H[i-1]`). Instead, we must remove all blocks which are in the range `H[i-1] - H[i]`.

The conditional I added which compares the range with the size of the `potentialBases` keyspace is added for performance reasons to ensure we always do the least work possible, and iterate through the smallest number of values.

EDIT:

Here's an alternative approach with a stack:

```
def solution(H):
    if len(H) == 0: return 0
    if len(H) == 1: return 1
    count = 0
    stack = []
    last = 0
    for i in range(0, len(H)): 
        if H[i] > last:
            count += 1 
            stack.append(H[i])
            last = H[i]
        elif H[i] < H[i-1]:
            while (len(stack) > 0 and H[i] < stack[-1]):
                stack.pop()
            if (len(stack) == 0 or H[i] != stack[-1]):
                count += 1
                stack.append(H[i])
            last = H[i]
    return count
```

Comment: stack is better suitable for this problem

Comment: @sahasrara62 could you share a working code example?

Comment: here [solution by predactor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26228432/manhattan-skyline-cover-failing-some-test-cases)